# What can I do against people downvoting out of spite?

Tags: discussion, moderators, down-votes

In a recent weeks I received quite a few downvotes, unfortunately *nearly* all of them are gifted to my questions without even a single negative comment (If it was for answers I feeling that downvoter at least really thinks my answer is bad to spend one point and open a discovery option for me). I can guess who are possible downvoters. e.g One of them is the one that I discussed with him a long time ago about the meaning of "natural problem" and after that discussion and considering that moderator supported me he started to downvote me (well I received some downvotes right after the question closed and I do not think it was by another one, and it was in another site but same user here). I don't know how to deal with these downvoters, specially if they downvote with fake accounts. Shall I downvote those people randomly or there is a logical way and e.g moderators can support in this situation. I do not think randomly in few weeks downvoters understand that almost all of my questions are bad (I asked not many questions, but the newest one is more than two year old!), but if they are really bad I like to have your help (particularly downvoters) to improve them.

P.S1: Before the recent weeks, in this site I had less than 5 downvotes and most of them were just for one question which was an edge question at that time (3-4 years ago), but then very randomly! those downvoters discovered that almost all of my contribution (as a questioner) was bad.

P.S2: I did write a personal message to one of such downvoters but the downvoter didn't respond to me so I also downvoted some of his questions and he downvote back and one day I didn't respond to his downvotes, it was really childish downvoting without any strong logic.

P.S3: (Un)forunately I'm almost quite logical, I simply accept my faults but on the other hand I do not accept anyone else's fault, well I do think everyone is responsible for his mistakes. That means I'm neither modest nor arrogant. So if you think you are doing something logical, then answer this post (everyone who thinks I'm in a wrong track), otherwise downvote me or suppose you never seen this.

P.S4: By having a good reputation or bad reputation at CSTheory.SE no one gets good or bad TCS job, so I really cannot understand meaning of downvotes without any single comment except that maybe someone say someone hates me and as I'm not a person who hates anyone so I cannot understand even this, your non-reasonable downvote or upvote just makes the site even worse.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that you're posting this question in good faith when your stackoverflow profile says: "Do serial upvote or downvote and if you enjoyed by my answer assign bounty. The reason to encourage this (possibly bad) behavior is all of the moderators in SO are stupid guys"

Comment: @HuckBennett my stackoverflow has its own story and it's not related to this, if you think you are good detective let me tell the story. there I answered a question, which was a wrong answer I deleted my answer before anyone note that and edit it and undelete it then I received bunch of downvotes, I discussed about it on meta and true detectives like you said that because I removed it once  deserve that. and I received more downcotes. Anyhow it's not your business to detect what going in my mind and this is personal attack, but it's your business to say what is wrong with this post.

Comment: How many downvotes did you actually get? I looked at your recent questions and answers, and most of them had no downvotes. I downvoted one of them (the one where you suggested Ford-Fulkerson and said Orlin's algorithm wasn't good where Orlin's algorithm is for min-cost-flow, and Ford-Fulkerson is for max-flow, ***not*** the problem the OP was asking about). But I haven't been serially downvoting your answers.

Comment: ... And I didn't think a comment was necessary in that case, because somebody had ***already*** put up a comment saying that you were addressing the wrong problem, to which you had not replied.

Comment: @PeterShor, I discussed with OP in chat (that someone you mentioned), I think it was better to look at chat and see why I suggested that algorithm. I really think here is not a place to discuss about that question, if you move your comment there then we will see who is right and if I'm wrong I'll delete my answer. But about this post. Unfortunately you didn't read it carefully. I spoke about downvoting my questions were the newest one is 2+ year old.

Comment: I cannot understand why people are trying to be detective. I very explicitly said that I tried to make a direct dialog with at least one of downvoters that I'm sure he did some of them, he knows this and surely he seen my meta post, and if something is wrong he can say that. Everything about one side of downvotes is quite clear, being detective and talking about something irrelevant to this post makes no sense.

Comment: @PeterShor, I forgot to say that all of my questions received downvotes (1 or 2) in less than 3 months. Even nearly all of them are in recent weeks (less than 4 weeks: e.g: Feb 3,4,6,7,15), I really don't know what did you check! (In reputation graph they are more than clear!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want advice about what to do here is mine: ignore, don't engage or react with counteractions, move on.

There are some automated tools in place to make sure there is no mass down voting and roll back such votes. They are not perfect but they generally do a good job catching mass down voting. If after a few weeks you see that you are still regularly getting down votes on old posts contact moderators and ask them to have a look at it.

ps: The policy here is that people are encouraged but not required to comment when down voting. Down voting without commenting is an accepted behavior here. You can read more in the previous meta discussions about it. I think one common reasons for not commenting is to avoid engaging and wasting time and energy arguing with unpleasant people.

pps: You are here admitting that you have engaged in mass revenge down voting, don't revenge down vote in future, that can be a ground for suspension.

Comment: I'll try to do so. Unfortunately downvoter understand that if he downvote a lot, system detects, at start was like that (5+ Q per day and system reverse them all), but after a time (one of the downvoters) trained and started to downvote in a more clever manner. I also ignored for a long time, I appreciate that one can downvote without existence of any negative comment (even negative comments from other people for me is a reasonable reason to downvote without commenting myself) but it was just really unpleasent to get downvotes for questions which are very clear and in the scope.

Comment: @Saeed, it happens to everyone from time to time, we receive down votes without any good reason, I don't think it is a big deal as long as it is relatively infrequent. Moderators have tools in addition to the automated system to detect voting misbehaviors, and they can also ask SE to also have a look at it (SE has access to all voting and user data).

Comment: Just to note -- Kaveh is right, just let the mods know next time.  Definitely don't revenge downvote. (And try not to worry about it.)